# Two iOS Apps in one firebase project but that about the analytics panel

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I am trying to setup dev and prod version in firebase analytics. My only concern is, Would I be able to distinguish at the analytics charts level/Analytics dashboard, that what data is coming from dev and what is from the release version of an app.

Provided that release version is out in wild and also firing a lot of data.

my concern is would I be having bad data from dev if I am trying to shove dev and prod version in the same Project.

Or it's better than I should be making two projects, one for dev another one for prod so that data is not overlapped.

I am sure many of you folks already done it. I would appreciate some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to have them as separate projects. This way the data is not mixed, especially analytics for firebase doesn't have the same filters/views as GA for web.

[More documentation on how to do this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/#use_multiple_projects_in_your_application)